# App loading data slowly after a few interactions

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest

I have an android app which is mainly focused on retrieving displaying as well as writing data to an online database. I have several activities in the app which use different Asynctasks and http requests to load different data. When I launch the app everything loads swiftly, as well as when I switch between the different activities. However, if I switch fast between them, eventually the screen goes black and after about a minute the app reappears again and the data is loaded very very slowly. I'm not sure if this is a cache issue or something else.

LOGCAT

```
06-29 12:23:03.792  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp I/System.out﹕ AsyncTask #1 calls detatch()
06-29 12:23:03.792  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://altesting.byethost33.com refused
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:235)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeSB(DefaultRequestDirector.java:807)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:675)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:570)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:491)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:469)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.albert.betterapp.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:70)
06-29 12:23:03.802  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.albert.betterapp.OldBets$LoadAllGames.doInBackground(OldBets.java:99)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.albert.betterapp.OldBets$LoadAllGames.doInBackground(OldBets.java:79)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-29 12:23:03.812  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /185.27.134.108 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:188)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ ... 16 more
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp W/System.err﹕ ... 21 more
06-29 12:23:03.822  14635-14667/com.example.albert.bettertipapp E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
```

Comment: For a start Asynctasks works on UI thread after several seconds it works background thread, that`s why yr app screen is changed to black screen. Try to use _new Thread_.

Comment: Posted the logcat, I know this is rather a result of the apps inaction which makes the connection time out rather than the problem itself

Answer (score 0):

Are you cancelling you async task when you are going out from on activity i.e. on onStop() or onPause() ?

Comment: No I'm not, but when I close the activity they are already over and have loaded the data

Comment: Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption. If the app starts a HTTP call every time you enter the Activity, if you switch fast between them, you could have a lot of pending http requests. You must try to handle in a clever way the http request, for example stopping them when you exit from the activity using cancel() method on Asynctask or abort on HttpRequest. In addition, you can also, if possible, to cache the http request results.

Comment: I use finish() after I exit each activity, I thought this would kill all processes going on inside